# Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2 \Rightarrow n \nmid (2^n-1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2 \Rightarrow n \nmid (2^n-1)$.

I have tried a lot of different ways to do such as induction way or make the counter assumption then to show the contradiction, however, I didn't succeed.

Can anyone give me hints or solution to this ? Thank you.

Comment: what is the symbol you are using in the statement of the problem>

Comment: @AnuragA see my latest update